# hadoop service not starting after kerberizing cluster: zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, ambari

I kerberized my cluster today after zookeeper services are not coming up.
There is no activity in logs also. The ambari-server and ambari-agent seems to be working fine.

Comment: it would be great if you would provide exact Ambari version when asking a question. I don't see this code in latest source code

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was in ambari-env.sh file.Check for syntax errors in security stanza.

```
export JAVA_HOME={{java64_home}}
export ZOOKEEPER_HOME={{zk_home}}
export ZOO_LOG_DIR={{zk_log_dir}}
export ZOOPIDFILE={{zk_pid_file}}
export SERVER_JVMFLAGS={{zk_server_heapsize}}
export JAVA=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/zookeeper/*
export SERVER_JVMFLAGS="$SERVER_JVMFLAGS -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/$USER/hs_err_pid%p.log -Xloggc:/var/log/$USER/gc.log-`date +'%Y%m%d%H%M'` -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps "

    {% if security_enabled %}
export SERVER_JVMFLAGS="$SERVER_JVMFLAGS -Djava.security.auth.login.config={{zk_server_jaas_file}} -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps and -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps"
export CLIENT_JVMFLAGS="$CLIENT_JVMFLAGS -Djava.security.auth.login.config={{zk_client_jaas_file}}"
{% endif %}
```

When the cluster is kerb it also loads lower part of env file. There was an extra "and" between the GC FLAGS

```
XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps and -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps"
```

to

```
XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps"
```